# How to asynchronously retrieve realtime firebase data in JS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

so basically i've been doing a chat app in react.js and I reached that level where I'm not always receiving the data from the database, sometimes i receive it and sometimes not, and the state doesn't always gets updated, what can I do ?

```
import { Segment, Comment } from 'semantic-ui-react';
import MessageForm from './MessagesForm';
import MessagesHeader from './MessagesHeader';
import firebase from '../../firebase'
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import Message from './Message';

const Messages = () => {
  const [messagesRef, setMessagesRef] = useState(firebase.database().ref('messages'));
  const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);
  const [messagesLoading, setMessagesLoading] = useState(true);
  const {currentChannel} = useSelector(state => state.channel);
  const {currentUser} = useSelector(state => state.user);
  

  const addListeners = channelId =>{
    addMessageListeners(channelId);
  }

  const addMessageListeners = channelId =>{
    let loadedMessages = [];
    messagesRef.on('child_added', (snapshot) => {
      loadedMessages.push(snapshot.val())
      setMessages(loadedMessages);
    })
  }



useEffect(() => {
    if(currentChannel && currentUser){
    addListeners(currentChannel.id);
    }
  }, [])


  
  const displayMessages = messages =>{
    messages.length > 0 && messages.map(message => (
      <Message key={message.timestamp} message={message} user={currentUser} />
    ))
  }

  return (
    <>
    <MessagesHeader />
    <Segment>
      <Comment.Group className='message'>
        {displayMessages(messages)}
        
      </Comment.Group>
    </Segment>

    <MessageForm  messagesRef={messagesRef}/>
    </>
  )
}

export default Messages;
```

Answer (score 0):

your useEffect runs only on first render, so you should give something into the dependency array, or use react-redux-firebase, there is an in-built listener. :)

Comment: You're right, when I added the [addListeners] as a dependency, the app works like a charm but with an error in the console ( Maximum update depth exceeded.), how can I fix it? is react-redux-firebase the solution?

Comment: If u put addListeners as dependency you got an infinity loop. Maybe you can use a boolean, that changes from true to false, or useCallback for function, but react-redux-firebase can be a solution too. :)